# Is there a difference between log(z) and Log(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

In the same vein, Arctan(z) and arctan(z)?

I'm seeing both versions in the same sentence.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value OR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Complex_argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your source, the most common usage is that $\operatorname{Log}$, $\operatorname{Arctan}$ and so on denotes the principal branch of the function in question, and that $\log$, $\arctan$ etc. is the multivalued version of the same function.

**But** there are books that do the opposite, so you should always check with the text you are reading.